# Can I generate the interim java code in a scala project

Tags: java, scala, visualvm

I am trying to use VisualVM to profile my scala application. I have added the Go To Source plugin for VisualVM but of course it will only recognize Java code. Is there a way I can specify in my project build that it should also output the interim java code?

I know I can use the following command to do it at a file level:

> scalac -Xprint:parse Main.scala

But is there a way I can generate all the java code for a project to a specific directory?

Comment: What do you mean with _"interim java code"_?

Comment: Isn't scala not first converted to java and then compiled as java?

Comment: No, scala is directly converted into java bytecode. Not sure why VisualVM would only support java files - as it should work only with the generated bytecode and extract the line numbers from there.

Comment: I tried adding the src/main/scala folder for my project but when I click "Go to Source" I just get an error: "No source found for..."

Answer (score 1):

There is no interim java code. Scala compiles directly to JVM classfile code, without ever becoming Java code.